# Logging or detecting if an item is deleted

Tags: php, logging, yii

I just wanted to log if someone has deleted an item. This is my code

```
public function actionDelete($id)
    {   
        $model = new Apartments; //tbl_apartments
        $_log = new Log; //tbl_log
        $_log->issue = 'Tenant ' .$model->tenants. ' deleted ';
        $_log->date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $_log->save();

        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
```

It deletes well but it doesn't log it. =/ What must be the problem? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: does the Log model has rules method ?
if yes, can you tell me what is it?
validation is called before `save()`, if you don't want validation, use `save(false)`

Comment: What @AlirezaFallah said. If your model isn't saving, most likely validation has failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the errors why save method returns false;

```
$_log->save();
print_r($_log->getErrors());
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [onAfterDelete()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#onAfterDelete-detail) method in your model.